# Pass 2 array parameters into wasm

Tags: javascript, arrays, webassembly

I have a c++ function that accepts 2 arrays and multiplies them together.

```
void multData(unsigned char *arr1, unsigned char *arr2) {
   for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    arr1[i] = arr1[i] * arr2[i];
   }
}
```

When I compile it I allocate space for both arrays in the heap using malloc.

```
var mallocBuff = Module._malloc(arr1.length); 
var mallocBuff2 = Module._malloc(arr2.length);
```

Then after filling the newly malloced data with values I'll call it like this:

```
Module.ccall('multData', null, ['number'], [mallocBuff], [mallocBuff2]);
```

However after some testing I realize that only the first array is receiving the malloc pointer. The second array is just a bunch of 0's.

Is there anyway to pass 2 arrays into a wasm compiled function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ccall` signature is `ccall(ident, returnType, argTypes, args, opts)`.
[API Reference](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/preamble.js.html?highlight=ccall#ccall%20%22%22)

```
Module.ccall('multData', null, ['number', 'number'], [mallocBuff, mallocBuff2]);
```